# Operators precedence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have bet with my workmate about precedence operators and I really don't understand why in the lines below the Russian phrase does not writes to console:

`f = () => (console.log('димас проиграл') || 0);
0 && 5 === f();`

I the msdn docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/operator-subtractprecedence-javascript I see that in the first step we need to calculate equality operator (===). It means that we need to calculate 0 && 5 and f() values and after this compare it.
By calculation f() the string must be written to console, but it doesn't.

Comment: `0 && false`... should what?

Comment: `0 && 5 === f();` is `0 && (5 === f());` which as `0` is false `&&` short circuits and does not evaluate `5 === f()`.

Comment: every falsey value stops the evaluation of the following expression with a logical and between.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is the **logical and** operator, the syntax is as follows:

```
var result = expression1 && expression2;
```

The thing is, if `expression1` evaluates to false, its value will be the one returned, otherwise, `expression2` will be the returned value.

For example:

```
var result = false && getStuff();
```

Since the first expression is `false`, the comparison will stop there and return `false`, and `getStuff()` will not be evaluated.

In your case, `0` evaluates to false. So it is returned and `expression2` isn't even evaluated, so `f` is not executed.

See here for more information on [**logical AND operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/logical-and-operator-decrement-javascript).